# MySQL JDBC Connector Error

Tags: java, jdbc, mysql-error-1064, mysql-connector

I'm using the latest MySQL version ... in my java application with named pipe and I started receiving the following error like 20 times in a row:

```
 com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

 The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
at ......
at ......
at ......
at ......
  Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: All pipe instances are busy
... 4 more

 com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

 The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
at ......
at ......
at ......
at ......
  Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: All pipe instances are busy
... 4 more

 com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

 The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
at ......
at ......
at ......
at ......
  Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: All pipe instances are busy
... 4 more
```

The MySQL server is active and working properly through the command line and PHP. I'm using Windows 7 Ultimate. What is the cause of this java exception and how can I fix this?

Thank you.

Comment: Check your connection string (hostname and port), check if the database server is up and running, check for software blocking connections... etc and finally... show us your code and connection properties.